# DDD: How to resolve aggregate members needing dependencies?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have the following aggregate:

- Checkout (root)
- Requirement: CouponRequirement, AnotherRequirement, YetAnotherRequirement
- Coupon

A Checkout has many requirements that need to be fulfilled in order for a `Checkout` to complete. Each `Requirement` has a `fulfill(data)` method that is responsible for the fulfillment process.

One of those requirements is a `CouponRequirement` which, when fulfilled, needs to make sure there is stock for a particular coupon and reserve it. For this to happen I need access to a `CouponRepository` or `CouponService`.

How could I tailor my design to accomodate that dependency?

FulfillRequirementCommand

```
function handle($cmd) {
   $cho = $this->checkoutRepository->get($cmd->checkoutId);
   $cho->fulfillRequirement($cmd->requirementType, $cmd->requirementData);
}
```

Checkout

```
function fulfillRequirement($reqType, $reqData) {
    $req = $this->getRequirement($reqType);
    $req->fulfill($reqData);
}
```

CouponRequirement

```
function fulfill($data) {
    // check stock / reserve coupon
}
```

The common solution would be to pass a `CouponService` to fulfillRequirement. But fulfillRequirement takes care of many Requirement types, not just one.

Maybe I just need to abandon the generic approach and have multiple `fulfillRequirement`:

`fulfillCouponRequirement($data, $couponService)`
`fulfillClientInformationRequirement($data)`

.. etc

What do you guys think? even if you think of a different approach altogether I'd love to read about it.